# Axis interval spacing when plotting with pandas timedelta

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, matplotlib, timedelta

I'm trying to plot some columns in a dataframe that has pandas timedelta values as its index. When I plot it, all the points are evenly spaced along the x axis even if there's a variable time between.

```
time = [pd.Timestamp('9/3/2016')-pd.Timestamp('9/1/2016'),pd.Timestamp('9/8/2016')-pd.Timestamp('9/1/2016'),pd.Timestam\p('9/29/2016')-pd.Timestamp('9/1/2016')]
df = pd.DataFrame(index=time, columns=['y'],data=[5,0,10])
df.plot()
plt.show()
```

[Wrong spacing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZmie.png)

If instead I used dates instead of timedelta, I get the proper spacing on the x axis:

```
time = [pd.Timestamp('9/3/2016'),pd.Timestamp('9/5/2016'),pd.Timestamp('9/20/2016')]
df = pd.DataFrame(index=time, columns=['y'],data=[5,0,10])
df.plot()
plt.show()
```

[Right spacing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngK2R.png)

Is there a way to get this to display correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment, it's not fully supported yet in pandas. Please see [this issue on Github](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/8711) for more info.

For a quick workaround, you can use:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(df.index, df.values)
```

Here's an example of how you could play with the ticks to make them readable (rather than just a very large number)

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import datetime
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df.index, df.values)
plt.xticks([t.value for t in df.index], df.index, rotation=45)
plt.show()
```

[image: result]

Comment: Just added an example of how you can format the ticks after that... because they'll look rubbish by default (a very large number basically...).

If that's helpful, please vote the answer up and accept too if it solved your problem. Thanks!